# RGBA Alpha value doesn't effect the transparency of my DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple issue that I can't seem to fix for the life of me...

I have a background image -

```
<body style="background: url(C:\Users\patrick\Source\Workspaces\PropertyManager2\Images\CityScapeBackground.png)">
```

I then have a DIV on top of it -

```
<style type="text/css">
.Main { margin-top:30px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
</style>

<div style="width:1000px; height:600px; font-family:Calibri; background-color:rgb(128, 128, 128)" class="Main" >
```

This creates a DIV with a gray background. But when I try and make the background, of the DIV, slightly transparent -

```
<div style="width:1000px; height:600px; font-family:Calibri; background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.50)" class="Main" >
```

the preview and my browser (Chrome - 35.0) shows the DIV with a background that is completely transparent. This happens no matter what the Alpha value in the RGBA is.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There must be additional context that's missing.

Comment: @Nit, ya that would make sense. But it's quite a simple piece of code, what could I be missing?

Comment: The point I was getting at is that your problem isn't replicable from your current code, the problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I understand your issue, if you wrap a < body > tag with another element or place this element before < body >, browsers will ignore this and always render the < body > tag in first place.

As you said "I then have a DIV on top of it -", may this be your issue ?

Also, if you trying to add a div over an image so this div controls the "opacity" opacity on the img, you are doing wrong.

Try:

```
<body style="width:1000px; height:600px; font-family:Calibri;" class="Main" >
  <div style="width:1000px; height:600px; background: url(http://www.wallsave.com/wallpapers/1920x1080/ajax-fc/657997/ajax-fc-internationaal-657997.jpg)">
    <div style="width:1000px; height:600px; font-family:Calibri; background-color: rgba(248, 247, 216, 0.7);">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/bqry2/